# Mysql-workbench to create shared database?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I wans't exactly sure if this is the place to ask this question, so I apoligize if it is not. Here is my situation:

In my workplace we are currently building a huge spreadsheet with a collection of data relating to certain products. We would like to filter and process this data on several ways after the collection is complete. However the database should be accesed by anyone in my workplace network. So what I want to know is this: If I install mysql-workbench on every computer in my network, is there a way to create a database that can be shared (that means add/edit/delete entries) by all the people in that network? Can that be automated for those that are not computer savy?

Or do is it better to write a custom program that uses my-sql as a backend?

Thank you for your time and answer!

Comment: MySQL Workbench is a program that lets you connect to a database. It isn't *the* database itself. Database itself is located on a computer in your network. If you install workbench on every computer and if all computers can access the one with the database - then it works like you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! From what I've been reading the program allows the creation of the database itself, right?

Comment: One more thing the users of the database need to learn MySQL commands?+}

Comment: Correct, the program connects to MySQL server - and sends commands to that server. It gives you graphical user interface trough which you create databases, tables and so on. People using that program should learn MySQL commands - which, of course, is a bit tricky. That's why people build web apps (stackoverflow, facebook etc.) which people know how to use :) but if you get your co-workers to learn MySQL - please, let us know how you did it :)

Comment: Thank you so very much!!! I probably could get the people to learn the commands, but I like programming a lot more. So I'm probably going to go with the custom option though!!!

Comment: Good luck with your efforts and have fun along the way :)